# Export table with dependent variables on row, not columns from linear regression

Tags: export, regression, cpu-word

I am trying to export a table which includes testing different portfolios with two different linear models, CAPM and 4 Factor model. I have no trouble making the models, but I can't find out how to export them to my Word document looking like the attached picture below. When using Stargaze or LATEX I always get the portfolios as a column and the variables on the rows. This is a problem because I have 10 portfolios.

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz1Aj.png)

Hope someone know how to make this table.

Thanks in advance!

(The table is from Mark M. Carhart (1997) article "On Persistence in Mutual Fund Performance")

Answer (score 0):

If you use LaTeX to create the table and export it as pdf (so I assume you don't have to work with the cell data anymore) use a simple `tabular` with 12 columns, then use `multicolumn` to create the 2 models (first row in your pic). `multicolumn` let's you sepcify the amount of columns it should include, as well as the column to start from.

Then each row represents one of your portfolios.

> I always get the portfolios as a column and the variables on the rows.

How so? In LaTeX this won't happen, or do you use some other program to create the tables?

EDIT1

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule
        & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CAPM} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{4-Factor-Model}\\
        \cline{4-6} \cline{7-12}Portfolio & Monthly Excess Return & Std Dev & Alpha & VWRF & Adj R-sq & Alpha & RMRF & SMB & HML & PR1YR & Adj R-sq\\
        \midrule
        1A & & 0.75\% & 5.45\% & 0.27\% & & & & & & & \\
        & & & (2.06)& & & & & & & & \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After using your tabular and multicolumn I manage to make the table in Latex! Thank you! But I only managed to do it with some test data. The problem is that I have only made the tables by using a matrix and xtable. This does not have the t-value (the value in parenthesis below alpha and the other factors). Do you know how I can manage to make this table? I do not know how to get the data into Tex yet, but I assume google with help me with that. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I do manage to make one table with Stargazer by using this command:
`code stargazer(N10.bench, N30.bench, N10.4, N30.4, title = "Main Title")`.

This gives me tables as shown here [link (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf)]. But I still have the same problem that it the rows should be on the columns.